# Should I give HR/Employer my desired salary before my annual review?

Tags: performance-reviews, compensation, salary-review

Human Resources gave me a review template document which I'm to fill out with my accomplishments and desired compensation, and hand back in to them for critique before it goes to the boss before my review.

I feel strongly that filling out the compensation portion will be mandatory before HR approves it for the boss, however I am wondering if this is normal for businesses to do, and if I should go along with this as I intend to do, or if there is an important reason to throw this wrench in the equation by not providing the desired compensation before the actual review.

I am established in my role, and have a good working relationship with this small but growing company, and I know they are very serious about cutting costs wherever possible, even for wages and salaries, as any money-conscious business would be.

Comment: What do you expect would be accomplished by not filling out that portion?

Comment: @Kilisi Giving me a better hand in the salary negotiation. The boss would go into the review knowing more about the maximum they are prepared to offer, and not so much about the maximum I want them to offer, and less chance to think about what to negotiate me down to.

Comment: This is just an example. Like I said, I plan on giving them this information. So really I am just waiting for someone to say "that's not normal" or "here's why you shouldn't" before I go and do it.

Comment: "if this is normal for businesses". No. I've never seen that as part of a regular performance review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have already been explicitly told that part is mandatory, then I see no harm in just putting something like:

> I would prefer to wait until the review to discus this information.

Assuming that is what you want to do. As an employee, you have the right to voice your preferences. Just know when to back down if the company disagrees with them. In this instance, the worst case is they will respond and tell you it's required and you will then have to provide it.

Just be aware that if you do get to wait until the review to discus it, expect the response to be "I will get back to you on that one". Unless your manager already has approval for a "max increase amount", it's unlikely they will agree to anything you ask for during the review. This may be the reason why they ask for it, so they can finalise the review in one sitting - rather than having to arrange a follow up meeting.

Having said that, I see no problems with just listing your desired salary. The number doesn't affect how hard you are willing to negotiate with that. How much you are willing to accept, and the actions you are prepared to take if it isn't met is another consideration entirely. You also have the benefit that it may just work in your favour, your manager may completely agree with your claim and just say "yes".

Regarding how "normal" this is, I have personally never experienced it. But that's not to say it isn't common for others.

Answer (score 3):

The potential backlash of not filling out the form overweighs any vague idea you might have of advantages.

You shouldn't be negotiating without a firm idea of what you're negotiating for. That just puts you in a weak position because you're playing it by ear rather than being prepared.

Comment: What are the potential backlashes? Also, why would the OP be playing it by ear anymore so than if they filled in the form? From the OP point of view, they gain no extra preparation by listing the expected salary. It's not like the manager is providing their expectations back to OP.

Comment: I don't know where the idea came from that I don't know what I'm negotiating for, or that I'm playing anything by ear. Rather, it would be the employer who is playing it by ear, not knowing my salary request until the review meeting itself.

Comment: No, your manager usually has little or no control over the negotiations, you're just creating an issue and more work for multiple people where they don't expect one to exist. You'd be playing it by ear because you'd be responding to what they decide to offer you rather than negotiating for an amount you already knew. Quite possibly they're asking so they can do any negotiating before the review, this is normal enough, it stops the review from being sidetracked into other areas..

Answer (score -2):

A safe bet would be to put 20% above what you're currently making. It's high but not beyond the realm of possibility and it lets you negotiate down to 10%, which is still decent.

You could also put something ridiculous like $1,000,000 as the desired salary. It may not be a realistic expectation but they didn't ask about what you think is a realistic salary and even if they did how would you know what's realistic and what's not?

If you knew what was realistic the best answer would be to put the maximum dollar amount of what's realistic. As a general rule, employees want to maximize what they get paid whilst employers want to minimize what they pay out. imho the company shouldn't have to even ask you what you want to get paid - they should just assume you want to get paid the max amount and leave it at that.

As is your companies approach heavily favors gossips. Maybe person A told person B what they get paid and person B told person C what person A and person B get paid. In that scenario person C can make a much more educated guess as to what the max that they're willing to offer than you can.

Comment: _"You could also put something ridiculous like $1,000,000 as the desired salary"_ What do you think HR would do with his application if he ridicules them by stating such an amount?